# How to get/change the first paragraph in a selection via word-js?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I am developing an Add-In for Word with the javascript api. I am trying to display the text of the first paragraph in the selection. Later I want to change this paragraph.

However, already displaying the text fails if the paragraph is enclosed in a table. If table cells are selected, none of the paragraphs enclosed in the cells seem to be included in the context.document.getSelection().paragraphs collection.

Why is this the case? How am I supposed to navigate to the first paragraph in a selection if the selection includes a table cell in a big table?

Here is the code I use for debugging the problem:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function is run each time the page is loaded.
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
                // Do something that is only available via the new APIs
                $('#button').click(doSomething);
                $('#status').html('Everything is fine.');
            }
            else {
                // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
                $('#supportedVersion').html('This code requires WordApi 1.1 or greater.');
            }
        });
    };

    function doSomething() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            // get selection
            var selection = context.document.getSelection();
            // load the text of all paragraphs in the selection
            var paragraphs = selection.paragraphs.load('text');

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync().then(function() {
                $('#status').html(JSON.stringify(paragraphs.items));
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $('#status').html('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

The selection in the first image returns `[{"text":"Content21"}]`, as expected.

[image: Selection of a paragraph within a cell]

The selection in the second image returns no text at all: `[]`. The paragraps-collection seems to be empty. This does not seem to make any sense to me. There are paragraphs in the selection.

[image: Selection of a row containing paragraphs]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Word API but [according the documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document?product=word) the selection contains a range and the range contains a list of paragraphs in the table row selection case.

So you can try this:

```
var range = context.document.getSelection();
var paragraphs = range.paragraphs;
var textFirstParagraph = paragraphs.items[0].getRange().load('text');
```

Links to the documentation for further studies:

- [Document object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document?product=word)
- [ParagraphCollection object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraphcollection)
- [Paragraph object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph)
- [Range object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range)

Comment: Your code should be equivalent to mine. You are just unsing the variable name "range" instead of "selection" and the context.load() function, which is 100% equivalent to the object.load() function: http://buildingofficeaddins.com/loading-properties/

Comment: Michael Palm you're right about the `load` function. Anyway have you tried to access the paragraphs collection `items` field? https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraphcollection

Comment: Yes, as you see in my code, I am pretty printing the items array: `$('#status').html(JSON.stringify(paragraphs.items));`. And it works with the selection in the first picture.

Comment: To what I see in VBA it reflects the Word API. In VBA to access the text of a cell paragraph item you need to loop through the items and access their `Range` object and of this range object the `text` property. I see the word API provides an `getRange` method you can use.

Comment: A Range in word-js is different to VBA. A Range can comprise multiple paragraphs. So does the Range returned by getRange() according to the documentation.

Comment: Ok, have you tried my suggested approach? Get the first Item of your paragraph collection and from this you can get the range and finally the `text` property. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148417/discussion-between-bruno-bieri-and-michael-palm).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that all table related objects in word-js are only available with requirement set 1.3 and not with 1.1. Additionally, they are not listed in the menu on the left side in the docs

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph

even though, it is possible to browse them by clicking e.g. on the type of the "parentTable" property of the Paragraph-object.

Since I encountered an obvious bug in another crucial function of my version of word-js ( https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/961 ) and it seems like Requirement Set 1.1 is just not suited for the interaction with tables, I assume that this is a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/972

By the way: To increase the confusion, there is also a "TableData" object in the shared api ( https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/tabledata ) which seems like it is superseded by the table stuff of Requirement Set 1.3. I have no idea what this is doing and whether I should use that.